# How can I properly control the numbers and dots that appear in pagination?

Tags: php, pagination

I have custom pagination that allows me to modify the mark-up for the code WP outputs:

in **functions.php**

```
function wp_custom_pagination($args = [], $class = 'pagination') {

            if ($GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1) return;

            $args = wp_parse_args( $args, [
                'mid_size'           => 2,
                'prev_next'          => false,
                'prev_text'          => __('Older posts', 'textdomain'),
                'next_text'          => __('Newer posts', 'textdomain'),
                'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation', 'textdomain'),
            ]);

            $links     = paginate_links($args);
            $next_link = get_previous_posts_link($args['next_text']);
            $prev_link = get_next_posts_link($args['prev_text']);
            $template  = apply_filters( 'navigation_markup_template', '
            <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
                <div class="nav-links">%3$s<div class="page-numbers-container">%4$s</div>%5$s</div>
            </nav>', $args, $class);

            echo sprintf($template, $class, $args['screen_reader_text'], $prev_link, $links, $next_link);

        }
        add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', function() 
        { 
        return 'class="next"'; 
        }); 

        add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', function() 
        { 
        return 'class="prev"'; 
        });
```

This is how I call it in my template files:

```
<?php wp_custom_pagination([
   'prev_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Prev Page', 'textdomain' ), 
   'next_text' => __( 'Next Page <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>', 'textdomain' )
 ]); 
?>
```

Now, this works, for the most part, but I have a [live example](http://www.stepyouraimup.com/blog/page/4/) where I set it so I can only see 1 post per page for testing purposes. The pagination creates too many numbers, which breaks my styling, but that's more CSS, I am thinking of a solution. Can I make it look like this?:

[1][2][3]...[9]

[1]...[4] [5] [6]...[9]

[1]...[7][8][9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'mid_size' => 2,` controls how many numbers are shown each side of the current page. Currently you have it set to 2, which means you'll get 5 numbers (current and 2 each side).. except on the first and last page where you get 2 on one side but there are no numbers to show on the other side.

You can dynamically set the `mid_size` based on which page you are currently on:

```
global $wp_query;

$mid_size = 1; // default to 1 number each side

// Check if we are on the first or last page
$current_page = get_query_var('paged');
if ( !$current_page || $current_page == $wp_query->max_num_pages ) {
    $mid_size = 2; // 2 numbers before/after the current page
}

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, [
    'mid_size' => $mid_size,
    //... rest of code
```

All you do is check the `paged` query var, if it isn't set you're on the first page, if it equals the total number of pages you're on the last page.

If you're on page 3 or 2 pages from the last page you will have 1 number on one side and 2 on the other since the first and last page isn't included in the 'mid_size', but I'm not sure there is a way to easily prevent that as you can't control the start and end numbers independently.

I also just noticed that your previous/next posts links are the wrong way round (check your live example). They work opposite to how you would expect. If you read the docs, [they say](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link):

> Because post queries are usually sorted in reverse chronological order, next_posts_link() usually points to older entries (toward the end of the set) and previous_posts_link() usually points to newer entries (toward the beginning of the set).

Comment: I changed it the mid_size to 1 and it fits nicely. The dots on the left hand side work too, beautiful. Thanks!